# Lifetimes for GRAPH API access token and refresh token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token

Where can I configure lifetimes for GRAPH API access token and refresh token? I am invoking the GRAPH APIs from B2C app.

Comment: The access token is not determined by graph API it is determined in Azure AD.So you can make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use **powershell** to create a token lifetime policy and assign the policy to your service principal to set the token lifetime.

please see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-token-lifetime-policies).

Comment: No...not in user flow but I need it for GRAPH API.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t adjust token lifetime for tokens issued to confidential clients using client credentials/servicePrincipal in Azure AD.

If you are using delegated permission, then you can:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-token-lifetime-policies